# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed.

[image: Aron Ahmadia]
[image: Geoff Oxberry]
[image: Paul]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections once your site has graduated.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Thanks, Aarthi! Congratulations, David and Aron! I look forward to working with you both!

Comment: One thing should be disclosed immediately: Aron Ahmadia and I work in the same group at the same institution and even coauthor papers.  If the community feels that having us as 2/3 of the moderators is too much concentration of power in a small group, I'm willing to step down.  That's not to say that I think it's a problem; Aron and I are pretty fair and open-minded ;).

Comment: Wait, really? :O That means all three of y'all know each other in real life. I'm guessing that in "meatspace" the SciComp community is fairly tight-knit?

Comment: Most scientific subdisciplines are pretty small, but I would think it's still a rather surprising coincidence to have all three mods actually know each other.

Comment: I think the common connection among the three of us is David Keyes. David Ketcheson and I both received Computational Science Graduate Fellowships from the US Department of Energy, and Keyes was on the advisory board of that fellowship for a while. Keyes is currently involved with KAUST, which is where David and Aron both work now. I ended up hearing about the Stack Exchange site through David, which I think is part of how this coincidence came to pass.

Comment: Ah ha. Well, then, I'm honestly not concerned about your connection, fairly tenuous as it is. As far as I'm concerned, you're colleagues in the field but not necessarily directly. For the time being, unless the community objects, I think this will be a nonissue. We believe that you three are the right people to help shape and lead the site, and I am confident you three will be able to be professional about the whole thing. After all, this is Computational Science! In my experience, academic-type folk are the best as taking a proverbial step back. :D

Comment: Thank you so much for the nomination.  I know that it is just a temporary gig, but even so, I find it to be an honor and priviledge to serve the scicomp community.